# If and Syntax error python

Tags: python, syntax

good evening. I'm new to python but not programming. I'm currently having trouble with a program I'm writing but I don't understand why. I want to display overtime pay if the amount of hours worked is greater than 40 but less than 60. Unfortunately, every time I try to use the and keyword I'm getting a syntax error from the program. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
wage = eval(input("Enter in the employees hourly wage: ")) #get wage
hours_worked = eval(input("Enter in the number of hours worked: ")) #get hours
pay = wage * hours_worked # calculate pay
ot = ((hours_worked - 40 ) *  (1.5) * wage) + (wage * 40) 
double = ((hours_worked - 40 ) *  (2) * wage) + (wage * 40) 
#calculate overtime pay

if (hours_worked <= 40):
    print (pay)

if (hours_worked > 40 and < 60):
    print (ot)

if (hours_worked >= 60):
    print (double)
```

Comment: The error will also tell you *where* it happens; perhaps that helps (and you could add that to your question).

Comment: In Python (and every other language I can think of), you must give a condition on both sides of "and".  `if (hours_worked > 40 and hours_worked < 60`.  < 60 by itself is a syntax error.

Comment: There is no need to put parentheses around if conditions (even though about every answer here does). Please see the (any) tutorial.

Comment: Fun fact: in Python you can do `if 40 < hours_worked < 60:` for what you want.

Comment: It's that second if statement that you're having problem with.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (hours_worked > 40 and hours_worked < 60):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (60 > hours_worked > 40):
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can use either

```
if (hours_worked > 40 and hours_worked < 60):
```

or

```
if (40 < hours_worked < 60):
```

I should also point out that you don't really need an eval() in the first line. The function you really want to use there is int(). Should you publish this code for public use, people could write malicious code that would be executed with the eval() function.

Answer (score 1):

On line 11

`if (hours_worked > 40 and <60):`

That does not work in python. You can write it either like this:

`if (hours_worked > 40 and hours_worked < 60):`

Or a shorter way to write it is:

`if (40 < hours_worked < 60):`

Answer (score 1):

In the language background that python comes from, the `and` operator doesn't require matching values, it requires conditions. Therefore, It's trying to interpret `< 60` as a condition, instead of how you mean it to be a more pattern-match-style construct.
You'll need to turn it into a condition by replacing it with `hours_worked < 60`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hours_worked > 40 and < 60):
print (ot)
```

should be

```
if (hours_worked > 40 and hours_worked < 60):
print (ot)
```

instead. Python doesn't yet support repeating the variable between bitwise `if` conditions.

Comment: Thank you all for your help it was such an easy fix. I didn't know I had to include the variable a second time after the and. After going back in inserting it it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Good you are happy. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to include hours_worked in the second condition

```
hours_worked > 40 and hours_worked < 60
```

this happens because the interpreter cant understand this syntax. it parses the first condition and next it finds an "and". Thus it expects another condition. Instead it finds '<' symbol.